# How to get user in Django signals

Tags: django, django-signals

How can you get the user who is saving record in django signals?
I am using signals to fill in data when a user marks `completed = True` via a form.
I was hoping something like `instance.User` or `instance.CustomUser.username` would work, but it just throws errors that these don't exist in `Maintenance` model.

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.utils.timezone import utc
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone



class Maintenance(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    customerTag = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
    maintenanceItem = models.CharField(max_length=35,blank=True,)
    maintenanceDescrip = models.TextField(max_length=300,blank=True,)
    maintenanceNotes = models.TextField(max_length=300,blank=True,)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    dateDue = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True, editable=True)
    dateCompleted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True, editable=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    createdBy = models.CharField(max_length=35,blank=True,)
    completedBy = models.CharField(max_length=35,blank=True,)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.maintenanceItem)
    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse('equipmentdashboard',)


def check_complete(sender, instance,**kwargs):
    hasCompleteDate = instance.dateCompleted
    if not (hasCompleteDate is None):
        return
    else:
        isComplete = instance.completed
        if isComplete == True:
            completed_By = ?
            Maintenance.objects.filter(id = instance.id).update(completed = True, dateCompleted = timezone.now(), completedBy = completed_By,)


post_save.connect(check_complete, sender = Maintenance)
```

Comment: You have to do stuff related to the `request` object (the `user` is one of them) in your view. You can't use a model signal for that. To keep the logic with the model, just create a method on your model that takes the `user` as argument, but call that method from your view.

Comment: Are you constrained to using signals? Alternatively, if you are using a form, pass in the user (from the view) as a form kwarg. Then when you call the `save()` method on the form, you can save the user to your model.

Comment: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the help guys. I was able to accomplish everything in the view as opposed to using signals.